# error 1200 mismatched input 'as' expecting SEMI_COLON when using DayExtractor in Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to analyze Apache access log files using Pig: 
http://venkatarun-n.blogspot.com/2013/01/analyzing-apache-logs-with-pig.html

And i'm stuck with this Pig script:

```
grpd = GROUP logs BY DayExtractor(dt) as day;
```

When i execute that in grunt terminal, i get the following error:

> ERROR 1200:   mismatched input 'as' expecting
>   SEMI_COLON Failed to parse:   mismatched input 'as'
>   expecting SEMI_COLON

Function DayExtractor is defined from piggybank.jar in this manner:

```
DEFINE DayExtractor   
org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.util.apachelogparser.DateExtractor('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Ideas anyone?
I've been searching for awhile about this. Any help would be greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the author of the blog post got it to work, but as far as I know, you cannot use `as` in `GROUP BY` in pig. Also, I don't think you cannot use UDFs in `GROUP BY`. May be the author had a different version of pig that supported such operations. To get the same effect, you can split it into two steps:

```
logs_day = FOREACH logs GENERATE ....., DayExtractor(dt) as day;
grpd = GROUP logs_day BY day;
```

Comment: You can apply builtin functions on the key in `GROUP`, so you should be able to use a UDF.